# What is the difference between str(x) and x.str?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

**What I needed to happen:**

Get all commas in a Pandas DataFrame replaced with dots.

**What I tried to do:**

```
df.apply(lambda x: str(x).replace(",", "."))
```

When I tried this, I got an error:

*ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable.*

**What was the correct answer:**

(found on StackOverflow)

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(",", "."))
```

**My question:**

What is the difference between str(x) and x.str, and why only one of them worked?

Comment: I suggest you look up https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html vs https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str. The first is a Pandas series method, the second is a Python built-in. [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=0` [the default since you don't supply it] expects a Pandas series method.

Comment: Although they have the same name, but they are totally not related. `Class.foo` is not the same as `foo()`.

Comment: Well, where `x` is a `pd.Series` object,  `str(x).replace(",", ".")` results in a `str` object and `x.str.replace(",", ".")` results in a `pd.Series` object, so quite different

Comment: Another way of thinking about it... `str(x)` will take some object x and return a string version of x. `x.str` doesn't inherently change x. It just gives you access to the `Series.str` methods.

Comment: @jpp I've read the Pandas docs but forgot that apply() only expects series. This explains it. Thanks!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks for the intuition behind that!

Comment: @noah, thanks for the intuition behind that!

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.Series.str` (the .str.) gives you a series that it works on each column

`pandas.DataFrame.apply` works on columns or rows.  by default row (axis{0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0).

The difference is that `str(x)` is operating on the index of the dataframe, as `apply` operates on the axis=0 by default, and the `.str.` is returning a series